# HTML / Javascript Automatic ContentEditable Tags?

Tags: javascript, html, tags, contenteditable

I'm trying to build a basic browser based text editor for a diary, and I was wondering if anyone could point in the right direction of how to set up ContentEditable tags?

At the moment I've been following this guide here:

https://www.simonewebdesign.it/how-to-make-browser-editor-with-html5-contenteditable/

And have it working, however it requires you to enter the file, actually type something like `<h1>TEST</h1>` before you can then reopen the file and edit the aforementioned text.

I'm looking for a way to type in `<h1>` and the browser recognise that and turn the following text into a header, same thing for `<p>` too.

So to summarise I want to be able to do the following:

Open the HTML file, write `<h1>` and then the browser recognises I'm typing a header, `<p>` and then the browser recognises I am now typing a paragraph.

Any help is most welcome, I'm still quite new at this and I'm assuming it's going to require Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

This could get pretty tricky, since you'd have to basically monitor every change to the editable area, and because HTML tags enclose their content - so updating on the fly means setting invalid HTML. Here's a rough bit of code that sort of does what you're describing, but it's got a lot of constraints and isn't the most user-friendly experience. Still, feel free to build from it!

```js
var area = document.querySelector('#edit-me');
var tagOpen = false;


area.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {

  // Check for ">", aka period + shift
  if (e.keyCode == 190 && e.shiftKey) {

    // We toggle this flag so it doesn't convert the text to html
    // until the tag seems closed - ie until two '>'s have been entered. 
    // This will work for simple one-level html,
    // but will have issues with self-closing tags and nesting.
    tagOpen = !tagOpen;

    if (!tagOpen) {
      var areaContent = area.textContent;
      area.innerHTML = areaContent;
    }
  }

});
```

```html
<div id="edit-me" contenteditable>Click to edit</div>
```